# MSVS 2010 C code in HDF-EOS5 error

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, hdf5

I want to read `he5` format but I have an error in the `HDF-EOS5` library. My library version is HDF5 1.8.14, EOS5 1.15 and MSVS 2010.

This is my code:

```
void main()
{
    hid_t gridfileid = 0;
    hid_t gridid = 0;
    short *terrain[720];
    hsize_t i, j;
    int a = 0;

    for( a = 0; a < 720; a++ )
    {
        terrain[a] = (short*)malloc(sizeof(short) * 1440);
    }

    gridfileid = HE5_GDopen( "D:\\MyHDFEOS\\OMI-Aura_L3-OMAEROe_2004m1001_v003-2009m0114t094640.he5", H5F_ACC_RDONLY );
    if( gridfileid == FAIL )
    {
        printf( "he5 File Open FAIL!" );
        return;
    }

    gridid =HE5_GDattach( gridfileid, "ColumnAmountAerosol" );
    if( gridid == FAIL )
    {
        printf( "Grid Open FAIL!" );
        return;
    }

    HE5_GDreadfield( gridid, "TerrainReflectivity", NULL, NULL, NULL, terrain );

    HE5_GDdetach( gridid );
    HE5_GDclose( gridfileid );

    for( i = 0; i < 7; ++i ) {
        for( j = 0; j < 14; ++j ) {
            printf( "%d", terrain[i][j ]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");


    for( a = 0; a < 720; a++ )
    {
        free( terrain[a] );
    }

    free( terrain );
}
```

This code error.

```
  HE5_GDreadfield( gridid, "TerrainReflectivity", NULL, NULL, NULL, terrain );
```

'There is an unhandled exception in 0x76f315fe of HDF-EOS5.exe. 0xC0000005: Access violation'

What is this error?

Comment: Now found a solution! This code is wrong. Please refer to this link.  http://hdfdap.hdfgroup.uiuc.edu/examples/code/read_datafield_grid_OMI_Aura_L3_OMAEROe.c

Comment: Standard warning: Do not cast `void *` as returned by `malloc` & friends in C. This is **not** C++!

Comment: Oh!  I understand. Thanks Olaf!

Answer (score 1):

[According to the documentation](http://hdfeos.org/examples/c_he5_grid.php), in

```
HE5_GDreadfield( gridid, "TerrainReflectivity", NULL, NULL, NULL, terrain );
```

The `terrain` parameter should be thus:

```
short terrain[720][1440];
```

This is a single continuous block of 1,036,800 bytes of memory.

However, you use:

```
short *terrain[720];
```

Then allocate 1440 bytes at a time. This gives instead 720 blocks of non-contiguous memory each 1440 bytes long, so your code fails. Looking at the source code, I see the declaration for the function is:

```
herr_t   HE5_GDreadfield(hid_t gridID, const char *fieldname, const hssize_t start[],
                         const hsize_t stride[], const hsize_t edge[],
                         void * buffer);
```

The `terrain` argument is a `void *`, which means that any pointer be passed in, so if you use:

```
short *terrain;

terrain = malloc(sizeof(short) * 720 * 1440);

/* etc... */

HE5_GDreadfield( gridid, "TerrainReflectivity", NULL, NULL, NULL, terrain );

/* etc... */

free( terrain );
```

Then to access elements you would have to do:

```
printf( "%d", terrain[i * 1440 + j]);
```

Alternatively, you could use:

```
short (*terrain)[1440];

terrain = malloc(sizeof(short) * 720 * 1440);

/* etc... */

HE5_GDreadfield( gridid, "TerrainReflectivity", NULL, NULL, NULL, terrain );

/* etc... */

free( terrain );
```

Then to access elements you can use the more natural:

```
printf( "%d", terrain[i][j]);
```

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I understand, thanks to you!  Really very thanks!